# Distance between binary patterns

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, linear-algebra

I'm working on a clustering of maze patterns which are binary sequences of 0(available cell) and 1(brick). Is there a good way to define how similar patterns are? Suppose I have two patterns:

```
1000 and 0100
1000     0100
1000     0100
1111     0111
```

Obviously they are similar, but the metrics I tried give me the following results:Euclidean 2.64575131106; Cosine 0.537089950114; Jaccard 0.7. At the same time for the absolutely non-similar patterns like:

```
1000 and 1111
1000     0001
1000     0001
1111     0001
```

it gives me: Euclidean 3.16227766017, Cosine 0.714285714286, Jaccard 0.833333333333. What I don't like is that numbers are very close. I want something like 0.1 for the first case and 0.9 for the second. Is there a solution?

Comment: In digital communication, [Hamming distance](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.hamming.html) is frequently used for this.

Comment: You say "Obviously they are similar" but 1000 and 0100 are different in 2 out of four components.  At the same time,  you say that 1000   and  0001 are "absolutely non-similar " even though they differ in exactly two components. I think that you need to be able to say why you think that patterns are close or not.   Nevertheless, I will throw in one more option not yet mentioned [Levenstein edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)